# Trouble Passing C String in Struct

Tags: ios, objective-c, string

I'm having trouble getting a char* string from a passed struct.  I have the following code:

```
typedef struct {
    NSInteger id;
    char *title;
} Movie;

...

Movie movie = [self randomMovie];

NSInteger movieID = movie.id;
NSString *movieTitle = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:movie.title];
NSLog(@"movieTitle: %@", movieTitle);

...

- (Movie)randomMovie {
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
NSString *query = @"SELECT id, title FROM movies ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;";

Movie movie;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        // Get the id and title of the first
        movie.id = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
        movie.title = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
    }
}

NSLog(@"Random movie %d title: %@", movie.id, [NSString stringWithUTF8String:movie.title]);

sqlite3_finalize(statement);
return movie;
}
```

This gives me the output:

```
2013-03-13 10:10:39.438 Fabflix[89156:c07] Random movie 872011 title: Ray
2013-03-13 10:10:39.439 Fabflix[89156:c07] movieTitle: (null)
```

Does anyone know why the title string isn't being passed correctly from randomMovie?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not terribly familiar with the sqlite3 C API, but are you sure the `sqlite3_finalize()` call isn't destroying the C string returned from `sqlite3_column_text()`? You may need to `strdup()` that thing (and then remember to `free()` it later).

**Update**: Yep, from the docs:

> The pointers returned are valid until a type conversion occurs as described above, or until sqlite3_step() or sqlite3_reset() or sqlite3_finalize() is called. The memory space used to hold strings and BLOBs is freed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The memory returned by [`sqlite3_column_text` is released as soon as you call `sqlite3_finalize`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html). You need to copy the value to your own string first.

```
typedef struct {
    NSInteger id;
    NSString *title;
} Movie;

/* ... */

movie.title =
    [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
```